# Returning custom Object from WCF Service

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, datacontract

I have added a dll file as reference and I want to return this custom object from my wcf service. I am getting InvalidDataContractException exception. I cannot mark this class as [DataContract] because it is declared in referenced dll file. Is it possible to return this custom object that declared in the dll file?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do so directly. If you really cannot mark class with DataContract attribute, you can create wrapper class, mark this wrapper and convert to and from this class.